# Resolve forward references in modular architecture

Tags: c#, architecture, module

In my (C#) software project, I have a several modules (represented by separate Visual Studio projects) that - due to historical reasons - have lots of circular dependencies (tight coupling).

I'm currently trying to resolve/remove the circular references. I've already added dependency injection - but this, of course, doesn't resolve/remove the circular references.

So, I was thinking about using events to resolve the "forward" dependencies. Instead of calling forward dependencies directly, they would register then on this event.

However, some of these dependencies need to be executed before others, like this (dumbed down) example:

```
void DeleteCompany(int companyId)
{
    // must run before other dependencies
    ForwardDepend1.OnCompanyDeleted(companyId);

    // can run in parallel
    ForwardDepend2.OnCompanyDeleted(companyId);
    ForwardDepend3.OnCompanyDeleted(companyId);

    // must run as last command
    this.OnCompanyDeleted(companyId);
}
```

All classes of `ForwardDependX` depend on the current class; so these are the circular references I want to resolve.

Are there any existing patterns that solve this kind of "complex event" mechanism? Or are there maybe other, better ways to solve this problem?

I've tried googling this problem but I couldn't find any good keywords for the search.

Answer (score 0):

I think using events to improve a tightly coupled design is not the best choice, because they tend to make dependencies less obvious. And you really need to have all dependencies explicit to tackle the circular references.

**I suggest you rather apply the [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) and the [interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) in a step by step manner. Pass newly introduced interfaces in to their clients through the constructor and use DI to compose them.**

Also, a dependency visualizer really helps in these situations. I've used Resharper and [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) for these tasks in the past, both work well.

### Example of the DIP

Here is an example that shows how you can resolve a circular dependency with the DIP. So assume you have two classes that depend on each other:

```
class A 
{
  private readonly B _b;

  public A(B b) {
      _b = b;
  }

  public void DoIt() {
    // ...
  }
}

class B 
{
  public void DoSomething(A a) {
    a.DoIt();
  }
}
```

This means we have a dependency graph like this:

```
A <--> B
```

Now introduce an interface on the class that constitutes the weaker dependency, in this case `A` (because `A` is only used temporarily in `B`).

```
interface IA 
{
  void DoIt();
}

class A : IA
{
  private readonly B _b;

  public A(B b) {
      _b = b;
  }

  public void DoIt() {
    // ...
  }
}

class B 
{
  public void DoSomething(IA a) {
    a.DoIt();
  }
}
```

With the introduction of the interface, the dependency circle has been broken:

```
 A ----
 |     |
 v     v
IA <-- B
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't wrap my head around how these two principles would solve my ordering problem. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski They don't. My recommendation is not to use events to solve the circular dependency problem at all. You still need to sequentially call the right dependencies, but the circular dependencies are gone.

Comment: As far as I understood your question, this is the root problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

That wont solve your problem. Instead you should create multiple events and hook them up.

You say that you have dependencies 1-3 that must run on order on the `CompanyDeleted` event and that your own event handler should run last.

That is a fragile approach. Let's assume that the dependencies instead are named like this:

- MessageManager
- ProjectManager
- UserManager

The motivation is that the message manager must run first so that it can find all users from the user manager and all projects from project manager to be able to delete it's messages.

You can instead reverse that process. Listen on the event `UserDeleted` to delete all messages for a user and on the `ProjectDeleted` even to delete all messages for the project.

So now you have no temporal coupling between the event handlers of the `CompanyManager` as you only have one event handler for it.

It will of course mean more work as you have to identify new events and create them. The good thing is that you can solve the event subscription with the help of your IoC container.

Create a new interface called `IEventHandler<T>`:

```
public interface IEventHandler<T>
{
    void Handle(T evt);
}
```

and let your classes implement it:

```
public class UserManager : IEventHandler<CustomerDeleted>
{
    public UserManager(IUserRepository repos, IEventPublisher publisher)
    {
    }

    public void Handle(CustomerDeleted evt)
    {
        var users = _repos.FindUsersForCustomer(evt.CustomerId);
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            _repos.Delete(user);
            _publisher.Publish(new UserDeleted(user.Id, user.CustomerId));
        }
    }
}
```

The event publisher itself uses your container (for service location). The implementation varies from container to container:

```
public class EventPublisher : IEventPublisher
{
    public EventPublisher(IYourContainerInterface container)
    {
    }

    public void Publish<TEvent>(TEvent evt)
    {
        var handlers = _container.ResolveAll<TEvent>();
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            handler.Publish(evt);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.